# Is there a way to convert 'nb-NO' decimals to 'en-US' in javaScript or jQuery Or in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

"1 234 345,45678" Norwegian format , when converted I need 1,234,345.45678.
I'm changing it inside a kendo grid calling a function on client template.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `,` with `.` and all spaces from string and then convert it into a `Number` and finally get the string in `'en-US'` format like:

```js
const str = '1 234 345,45678'
const getFormattedString = (s, locale = 'en-US') => Number(str
  .replace(',', '.').replace(/\s+/g,'')).toLocaleString(locale, {minimumFractionDigits: 5})

console.log( getFormattedString(str) )
```

The good thing about converting it to a `Number` is that in future if you need string in a different format based on `de-DE` (German format) or any other locale you can easily do it by passing the `locale` param to the function like:

```js
const str = '1 234 345,45678'
const getFormattedString = (s, locale = 'en-US') => Number(str
  .replace(',', '.').replace(/\s+/g,'')).toLocaleString(locale, {minimumFractionDigits: 5})

console.log( getFormattedString(str) )

// German uses comma as decimal separator and period for thousands
console.log( getFormattedString(str, 'de-DE') )

// India uses thousands/lakh/crore separators
console.log( getFormattedString(str, 'en-IN') )
```